# A first chance exception of type 'StructureMap.StructureMapException' occurred in StructureMap.DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

Hello I'm getting this  exception thrown at me whenever I try to test a web application via visual studio, any ideas why? I'm building a project using MVC3 model and visual studio 2010

Exception: A first chance exception of type 'StructureMap.StructureMapException' occurred in StructureMap.DLL

Comment: What's the message and stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

[First chance exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx) might occur while debugging. They might be handled properly by your code and never propagate when running the application normally but nevertheless Visual Studio shows them in Debug mode. If you don't want to be bothered you could disable them in Visual Studio and they will no longer appear.